# On Error statement doesnt work when an error occurs inside a loop

Tags: vb6, error-handling

can this be a bug? or am i missing smt here?

```
Do While Not somevalue= ""

sorgu = "INSERT INTO somedb VALUES('" & somevalue & "')"
On Error GoTo est
rs.Open sorgu, cnn

j = j + 1

est: Loop
```

im getting unique key error but i dont wanna be prompted for it, just wanna resume next line.

`On Error` doesnt work when having this error.

i have to use `Do While Loop` cant change it for an err.

How can i avoid being prompted for error and why `On Error` statement not working at this point.

Comment: In VB6 IDE menu `Tools->Options` select `General` tab and set `Break on unhandled errors` only.

Comment: thats nice to know u should ve sended that as an answer u know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your example, but to answer your question, change your error handler to **On Error Resume Next** or add an actual error handler, check the err.Number there and decide what action to take.

```
    Do While Not somevalue= ""

        sorgu = "INSERT INTO somedb VALUES('" & somevalue & "')"
        On Error GoTo est
        rs.Open sorgu, cnn

        j = j + 1

    Loop

est:
    'some error handling code
```

I would also suggest moving your GoTo statement to just ahead of your Do statement. As you have it you unnecessarily assign the On Error redirect each time the loop executes.

```
    On Error GoTo est
    Do While Not somevalue= ""

        sorgu = "INSERT INTO somedb VALUES('" & somevalue & "')"
        rs.Open sorgu, cnn

        j = j + 1

    Loop

est:
    If err.Number = (unique key error)
        Resume Next
    Else
        MsgBox "An error occurred while inserting records. Error " & CStr(Err.Number) & ", " & Err.Description
```